# How to print every input value which come from a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to know how to print every value I got from a while loop. I want this code can print every account, first num, and second num out.

Example:

```
input account: 5555

input first num: 2323

input second num: 4343

print: "Thank you. Next"

(Continue)

input account: 6666

input first num: 1313

input second num: 5353

print: "Thank you. Next"

(Continue)

input account: -1

print: "Finished Entering Account"

(Break)





output:

5555  2323  4343

6666  1313  5353
```

Code:

```py
def getaccount(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= -1 and num <= 99999:
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")


def getfirstnum(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= 0 and num <= 9999:
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")  


def getsecondnum(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= 0 and num <= 9999:
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")


# Main
while (True):
    num1 = getaccount("Enter a 5 digit account number (#####) or enter -1 to end:")
    if num1 == -1:
        print("Finished Entering Account.")
        break
    num2 = getfirstnum("Enter the first gas reading (####): ")
    num3 = getsecondnum("Enter the second gas reading (####): ")
    print("Thank you. Next.")
```

Comment: The question is incomplete. Which language are you referring to? And provide a code snippet

Comment: I don't understand your problem - why don't you use `print()` to print it?

Comment: if you mean to print values AFTER leaving `while` loop then in `while`-loop you have to put values in list or dictionary and later print values from list or dictionary.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right, you want to print all values after exiting the while loop.

```py
def getaccount(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= -1 and num <= 99999:
                num1_list.append(str(num))
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")


def getfirstnum(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= 0 and num <= 9999:
                num2_list.append(str(num))
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")  


def getsecondnum(prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            if num >= 0 and num <= 9999:
                num3_list.append(str(num))
                return num
            else:
                print("Outside range, try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Unacceptable entry. Try again.")


def printnumlists():
    print('Accounts: ' + ', '.join(num1_list))
    print('First values: ' + ', '.join(num1_list))
    print('Second values: ' + ', '.join(num1_list))


num1_list = []
num2_list = []
num3_list = []

# Main
while (True):
    num1 = getaccount("Enter a 5 digit account number (#####) or enter -1 to end:")
    if num1 == -1:
        print("Finished Entering Account.")
        break
    num2 = getfirstnum("Enter the first gas reading (####): ")
    num3 = getsecondnum("Enter the second gas reading (####): ")
    print("Thank you. Next.")

# Print after finished
printnumlists()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem, thanks :D